# How move main menu to center in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

my main menu is aligned in left I want to move my main menu items in the center of the page.I'm using protostar template.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Joomla 3.5 or later, create a file at: `templates/protostar/css/user.css` if it doesn't already exist and add the following contents to the file:

`.navigation {
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation .nav {
  display: inline-block;
}`

Comment: I created the user.css file and added the code above, but it had no effect.

Comment: Try clearing the Joomla cache and any server side cache e.g. SiteGround Dynamic Cache if enabled.

Comment: I realized the new user.css file wasn't saved in the proper directory. I moved it to the CSS folder via explorer and restarted the service.  That did it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You open the file template.css in folder **templates\protostar\css\template.css** if you use template protostar.
And find the line of code:

```
.navigation .nav-pills {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

add code:

```
.navigation .nav-pills {
   margin-bottom: 0;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

[As the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLFMv.png)